# Why does test pass when it should fail - Selenium/Python

Tags: python, selenium

I am using Python 2.7.8 and Selenium 2.45.0. I am going to use Amazon.com as my example in this question. My test looks like this:

```
class Test1(unittest.TestCase):
    def testStep1(self):
        self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.browser.get("http://www.amazon.com")
        if self.browser.find_element_by_link_text('Amazon'):
            assert(True)
        else:
            assert(False)

    def testStep2(self):
        self.browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#nav-link-shopall').click()
        directory_span = self.browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="siteDirectoryHeading"]')
        for span in directory_span:
            if "EARTH'S BIGGEST SELECTION" in span.text:
                assert(True)
            else:
                assert(False)
```

What is happening is that when the button is clicked, it does not go to the desired page. Because of this, the "EARTH'S BIGGEST SELECTION" never displays, yet the assertion says it passed. Why is it doing this?

NOTE: I changed the code and it is now working as expected. I changed the above to:

```
    def testStep2(self):
        (webdriver.ActionChains(self.browser)).double_click(self.browser.find_element_by_id('nav-link-shopall')).perform()
        directory = self.browser.find_element_by_id('siteDirectoryHeading').text
        if "EARTH'S BIGGEST SELECTION" in directory:
            assert(True)
        else:
            assert(False)
```

The code is now finding the directory_span text and is passing as hoped. Thanks for the input and help! I just didn't realize that I needed a `double_click()` in lieu of a `click()`.

Comment: Can you `print span.text` and show us what it displays?

Comment: could you replace assert(True) with print span.text and tell us what it prints?

Comment: I entered a `print.span.text` and it didn't print anything, yet still said the step was a Success.

Comment: Can you debug it and see why it is passing?

Comment: Just says "Process finished with exit code 0"

Comment: Are you sure that  `testStep2` runs at all? That would be the first thing I'd check.

Comment: Are you sure the test is running? `print.span.text` is not valid Python.

Comment: When I execute the test, the browsesr opens, navigates to the desired webpage. On stepTest2, it displays the dropdown list, rather than going to the desired page as it would if you would click with a mouse outside of the test.

Comment: my typing `print.span.text` was a typo, I have `print span.text` in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that if there are no elements found by `self.browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="siteDirectoryHeading"]')`, you would not get an error, but an *empty list*.

This is what actually happening here - *`directory_span` is an empty list* and the body loop is never executed. This is why you see the test passes.

Comment: So, because the page never loads and the elements are not found, there are no errors? Is that correct? How would you bypass this to ensure it does error if the page does not load correctly?

Comment: @Brenda in this case, I would check that `directory_span` is not an empty list. E.g. `self.assertTrue(directory_span)`.

Comment: @Brenda btw, how did you find that `siteDirectoryHeading` id - I don't see elements with this `id` on the main amazon page..

Comment: if you look at the code on the directory page, it has `<h2 id="siteDirectoryHeading">EARTH'S BIGGEST SELECTION</h2>`. Also, substituted to use `self.assertTrue(directory_span)` and it is still passing.

Comment: @Brenda yeah, but the directory page is not opened and there are no elements with `siteDirectoryHeading` id on the main amazon page. `directory_span` becomes an empty list.

Comment: @Brenda could you also try the following check: `assert(len(directory_span) > 0)`?

Comment: it is odd...it even passed that test step.

Comment: I figured out what my issue was. I was using a single click, and not a double click. I replaced my single click step with `(webdriver.ActionChains(self.browser)).double_click(self.browser.find_element_by_id('nav-link-shopall')).perform()` and it worked perfectly.